# My macro is not working properly it stuck in loop not performing after first row activity

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

My macro is not working properly it stuck in loop not performing after first row activity

```
Sub ClearWordBoldStyle()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim doc As Object ' Word.Document
    Dim wordApp As Object ' Word.Application
    Dim rng As Object ' Word.Range
    Dim lastRowA As Long
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with the actual sheet name

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to get the existing Word application
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        ' If Word is not already running, create a new instance
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed or accessible.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    wordApp.Visible = False ' Set to True if you want to see the Word application during execution

    ' Open the Word document (Replace "C:\Path\to\Your\Document.docx" with the actual path)
    Set doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\to\Your\Document.docx")

    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Copy entire range from Column A to Column B
    ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRowA).Value = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRowA).Value

    ' Find all instances of the string in the Word document for each value in Column A
    For i = 1 To lastRowA
        ' Get the string from column A for each row
        searchString = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value

        Set rng = doc.Content
        With rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = searchString
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1 ' wdFindStop (Stop searching at the end of the range)
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            ' Select and apply bold style for each instance found
            Do While .Execute
                rng.Font.Bold = True
            Loop
        End With
    Next i

    ' Close the Word document
    doc.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Quit the Word application
    wordApp.Quit

    ' Clean up the objects
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

    MsgBox "Task completed.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

I do while , Nested loop kindly help

Comment: this is macro related first copy the Value from excel column A to Column B and add space in the end of column B string. Now pick the string from B column and search in assigned document and select the all instance and clear style for all instances . after that pick the string from column A and search in assigned document and apply bold style

Answer (score 0):

RepalceAll is mroe efficient way to get it done in Word. It supports to set replacement format.

btw, I don't know why you don't save word document. `SaveChanges:=False` means close document w/o saving change.

```vb
Sub ClearWordBoldStyle()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim doc As Object ' Word.Document
    Dim wordApp As Object ' Word.Application
    Dim rng As Object ' Word.Range
    Dim lastRowA As Long
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim i As Long
    ' Set the workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with the actual sheet name
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to get the existing Word application
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        ' If Word is not already running, create a new instance
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed or accessible.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    wordApp.Visible = True ' Set to True if you want to see the Word application during execution
    ' Open the Word document (Replace "C:\Path\to\Your\Document.docx" with the actual path)
    Set doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\to\Your\Document.docx")
    ' Set doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Copy entire range from Column A to Column B
    ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRowA).Value = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRowA).Value
    ' Find all instances of the string in the Word document for each value in Column A
    For i = 1 To lastRowA
        ' Get the string from column A for each row
        searchString = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
        With doc.Content.Find
            .Text = searchString
            ' Set replacement text and font
            .Replacement.Text = searchString
            .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchByte = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            ' replace all 
            .Execute Replace:=2
        End With
    Next i
    ' Close the Word document
    doc.Close SaveChanges:=True
    ' Quit the Word application
    wordApp.Quit
    ' Clean up the objects
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    MsgBox "Task completed.", vbInformation
End Sub
```